# Unable to install the selected kernel

Tags: kernel, boot, linux-kernel, system-installation, netboot

I have problem with my DVD drive. It's corrupted and when I'm trying to install Ubuntu it stucks (even with the miniISO)

I was able to successfully start the OS from system rescue CD.

I'd like to have a possibility to copy minimum information from CD and instead of it download the most files from the internet because my DVD drive won't manage it and stucks.

I can't use USB installation, my laptop doesn't support it.

I succeeded according to [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet) and downloaded [netboot files](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz). I copied [files and directories](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/ubuntu-installer/i386/) to my `/boot` directory on `/dev/sda1` partition and performed the steps in the guide.

```
root=hd(0,1)
linux /boot/linux
initrd /boot/initrd.gz
boot
```

After the command `boot` in Grub and in the process of `installing the base system` I got this error

```
Configuring linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic
Unable to install the selected kernel
An error was returned while trying to install the kernel into the target system.
Kernel package: 'linux-generic'.
Check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details.
```

[/var/log/syslog](http://privatepaste.com/64ce3f978e)

Did I something wrong? Can I repair this error?

Comment: Tell us the what you see from tty4 (press alt + f4)

Comment: @warl0ck I appended /var/log/syslog file to the question.

Comment: @slafat01 Yes 12.10, the exact links to files are in the question.

Comment: I see this in the syslog - "This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU." You may have to install the 'linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic-pae' package instead, and use that for the kernel.

Comment: @slafat01 Is there a link to download that file and use it in Grub? Or the only option is to install the deb package? I don't have working system now, I'm on rescuecd and it has Gentoo Linux.

Comment: I will delete this question, because there is complex answer on askubuntu.com which gives me good understanding of the problem.